# RegEx for extracting number from a string

Tags: c#, regex

I have a bunch of files in a directory, mostly labled something like...

PO1000000100.doc or .pdf or .txt
Some of them are PurchaseOrderPO1000000109.pdf

What i need to do is extract the PO1000000109 part of it. So basically PO with 10 numbers after it...
How can I do this with a regex?

(What i'll do is a foreach loop on the files in the directory, get the filename, and run it through the regex to get the PO number...)

I'm using C# - not sure if this is relevant.

Comment: `(PO\d{10})` - and filler to make up the minimum of 15 characters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
String data = 
  Regex.Match(@"PO\d{10}", "PurchaseOrderPO1000000109.pdf", 
    RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Value;
```

Could add a Regex.IsMatch with same vars above ofc :)

Comment: Using `<pre><code>` ... `</code></pre>` tags could you perhaps consider splitting up the expression across lines to make it slightly more readable :)

Answer (score 2):

If the PO part is always the same, you can just get the number without needing to use a regex:

```
new string(theString.Where(c => char.IsDigit(c)).ToArray());
```

Later you can prepend the PO part manually.

**NOTE**: I'm assuming that you have only one single run of numbers in your strings. If you have for example `"abc12345def678"` you will get `"12345678"`, which may not be what you want.

Answer (score 1):

```
Regex.Replace(fileName, @"^.?PO(\d{10}).$", "$1");
```

Put stars after dots.

Answer (score 1):

```
string data="PurchaseOrderPO1000000109.pdf\nPO1000000100.doc";
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(data, @"PO[0-9]{10}");
foreach(Match m in matches){
    print(m.Value);
}
```

Results

```
PO1000000109
PO1000000100
```

Answer (score 0):

This RegEx will pick up all numbers from a string `\d*`.

As described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

A possible regexp could be:

```
^.*(\d{10})\.\D{3}$
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var re = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("(?<=^PurchaseOrder)PO\\d{10}(?=\\.pdf$)");
Assert.IsTrue(re.IsMatch("PurchaseOrderPO1234567890.pdf"));
Assert.IsFalse(re.IsMatch("some PurchaseOrderPO1234567890.pdf"));
Assert.IsFalse(re.IsMatch("OrderPO1234567890.pdf"));
Assert.IsFalse(re.IsMatch("PurchaseOrderPO1234567890.pdf2"));
```